# Is a "differentiable" equation really guaranteed to be continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

There is this theorem I just learned that states a differentiable (everywhere) function is also continuous everywhere.

Here is a popular proof for it;
$\lim_{x=c}{[f(x)-f(c)]}=\lim_{x=c}{[f(x)-f(c)]}•\frac{x-c}{x-c}=f'(x)•0=0$

Here is this question that's in my homework:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2-16, x<9
\\12\sqrt{x}, 9\leq x
\end{cases}$$

The function is differentiable because the two side derivative limit exist;
$$\lim_{x=9^+}{\frac{f(x)-f(9)}{x-9}}=\lim_{x=9^-}{\frac{f(x)-f(9)}{x-9}}$$

For the cases of x approaching 9 from the left (or $9^-$), $f(x)$ is $x^2-16$. For x approaching 9 from the right (i.e., $9^+$) $f(x)=12\sqrt{x}$.

We know from the above operations that (**referring to the proof**) f'(x) is a finite real number. Therefore $\lim_{x=c}{f(x)}=f(c)$ and so the function must be continuous. However, $x^2-16x \neq 12\sqrt{x}$ for $x=9$.

Comment: The function is not differentiable at $x=9$.

Comment: Why do you say that the two-sided derivative limit exists?

Answer (score 4):

We show  that $f(x)$ is *not differentiable* at $x=9$, by using the definition of the derivative.  Since $f(9)=36$, we want to know whether 
$$\lim_{x\to 9}\frac{f(x)-36}{x-9}$$
exists.

If $x\lt 9$, then
$$\frac{f(x)-36}{x-9}=\frac{x^2-52}{x-9}.$$
It is clear that $\dfrac{x^2-52}{x-9}$ becomes very large negative as $x$ approaches $9$ from the left.

Comment: It can't be or there is something wrong with what I know. I thought if x approaches 9 from the left, f'(x)=2x. So f'(9) is 18. From the right, f'(x)=6/sqrt{x}. So f'(9) is 2. I made a mistake in saying the two side limit exists. I think the limit fraction is a 0-0 indeterminate form as x approaching 9 and something must be cancelled out.

Comment: As $x$ approaches $9$ from the left, $f'(x)$ does indeed approach $18$.  We get a similar result approaching from the right. So if the derivative at $9$ *existed*, it would be $18$. But the calculation in the answer above shows that the derivative at $x=9$ does not exist.

Comment: So I should always be using limit when checking for differentiability?

Comment: Most of the time differentiability follows from standard theorems. tt is typically only at "weird" points that we need to go back to the definition.  In your problem, the only weird point is $x=9$.

Comment: But note that in your problem, we need not have gone back to the definition. For it is clear that $f$ is not continuous at $x=9$, so by a standard result $f$ is not differentiable there. It is only because you cast doubt on the standard result that I went back to the definition of differentiability to show non-differentiability.

Comment: What is "tt"? Are you saying typically the power rule works fine? Why then in this (special) case doesn't it work and its result different from that of the limit?

Comment: "tt"  is a typo for "It". The power rule works fine for all $x\ne 9$. But $f$ is defined by different polynomials on the left and right of $9$.

Comment: I know it's defined by different functions. But let's know just talk about left of 9. Why is limit method yielding a different result than the power rule method?

Comment: Very roughly speaking, it is because $f(9)=36$, and the power method applied to $x^2-16$ "thinks" that $f(9)=81-16=65$.